# Сумирование суммы по нарастающей

Tags: php, mysql

Делаю вывод сумм по месяцам:

```
$OReqSQL = mysql_query("SELECT LPAD(YEAR(MIN(`datesort`)),4,'0'),LPAD(MONTH(MIN(`datesort`)),2,'0'),MONTHNAME(MIN(`datesort`)) FROM dfort_finance_client WHERE contract = '$id_contract'GROUP BY MONTH(datesort) ORDER BY dfort_finance_client . datesort ASC");
while ($Req = mysql_fetch_array($OReqSQL)) {
    $PayDohodSQL = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(summ) FROM dfort_finance_client WHERE contract = '$id_contract' AND datesort BETWEEN '".$Req[0]."-".$Req[1]."-01' AND '".$Req[0]."-".$Req[1]."-31' AND type_pay = '1' ORDER BY id DESC"); 
    $PayDohodPoFO = mysql_result($PayDohodSQL, 0);
    $PayRashodSQL = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(summ) FROM dfort_finance_client WHERE contract = '$id_contract' AND datesort BETWEEN '".$Req[0]."-".$Req[1]."-01' AND '".$Req[0]."-".$Req[1]."-31' AND type_pay = '2' ORDER BY id DESC"); 
    $PayRashodPoFO = mysql_result($PayRashodSQL, 0);
    $SaldoPoFO = $PayDohodPoFO - $PayRashodPoFO;
    echo $SaldoPoFO;
}
```

Как мне теперь сделать вывод сумм по нарастающей? Т.е. если `Январь: 100`, `Февраль: 50`, `Март: 120`, то должно выводить в другой таблице: `Январь: 100`, `Февраль: 150`, `Март: 270`.

Comment: Январь: 100, Февраль: 100+50=150, Март: 150+120=270

Comment: _Как мне теперь сделать вывод сумм по нарастающей?_ Определитесь, хотите Вы считать нарастающий итог на клиенте (PHP) или получить его в запросе, считая на MySQL-сервере? если второе - то показывайте ТОЛЬКО MySQL-запросы, без всей вот этой PHP-обвязки...

Comment: Наверно на клиенте (PHP)

Comment: ну дак и считайте сумму в цикле вывода, в чем проблема то?

Comment: @Akina Все оказалось на много проще! `$SaldoPoFOj += $SaldoPoFO;
echo $SaldoPoFOjj = number_format($SaldoPoFOj, 2, ',', ' ');`

Answer (score 3):

Ваша задача решается одним SQL-запросом:

```
SELECT A.*, @s:=@s+dohod-rashod Saldo
  FROM (
   SELECT LPAD(YEAR(MIN(`datesort`)),4,'0') Y, LPAD(MONTH(MIN(`datesort`)),2,'0') M,
          MONTHNAME(MIN(`datesort`)) MName,
          MIN(datesort) datesort,
          SUM( IF(type_pay=1,summ,0) ) dohod, SUM( IF(type_pay=2,summ,0) ) rashod
     FROM dfort_finance_client
    WHERE contract = $id_contract
    GROUP BY MONTH(datesort)
  ) A, (select @s:=0) B
 ORDER BY datesort
```

Хотя, конечно, можно и не делать внешний уровень запроса, считающий нарастающий итог, а посчитать его в PHP:

```
var $Saldo=0;
while ($Req = mysql_fetch_array($OReqSQL)) {
  $Saldo=$Saldo+$Req['dohod']-$Req['rashod'];
  echo ...
}
```